# I cannot make 7Segment 4Digit TM1637 to work

Tags: pi-3, display, led

I bought 7Segment 4 Digit TM1637
And i wan to make it work with Raspberry Pi 3B

However, it doesn't work

I think i wired everything correctly,
and i used this python lib
https://pypi.org/project/raspberrypi-tm1637/

However, it's freeze at this step

```
tm.write([127, 255, 127, 127])
```

can someone please help how can i debug this ?

Thank you so much

[image: Wiring Raspberry Pi 3B with TM1637]
[image: Wiring Raspberry Pi 3B with TM1637]
[image: Wiring Raspberry Pi 3B with TM1637]
[image: My code with TM1637]

Comment: Red and black are normally used for power (red being +ve) not purple and yellow :-) - do you have a picture of the LED connections so we can see the pin out please!  If you have the correct cables I would remove the breadboard - cheap jumpers can wobble and make poor connection in boards so I would check them if you only have M-F leads.  Any reason you are using different pins to the library shows?

Comment: You have the wires on the wrong GPIO pins. You have confused left and right.